# Transform a nested list without copying or losing precision

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am using Mathematica 7 to process a large data set.  The data set is a three-dimensional array of signed integers.  The three levels may be thought of as corresponding to *X* points per *shot*, *Y* shots per *scan*, and *Z* scans per *set*.

I also have a "zeroing" shot (containing *X* points, which are *signed fractions of integers*), which I would like to subtract from every shot in the data set.  Afterwards, I will never again need the original data set.

How can I perform this transformation without creating new copies of the data set, or parts of it, in the process?  Conceptually, the data set is located in memory, and I would like to scan through each element, and change it at that location in memory, without permanently copying it to some other memory location.

The following self-contained code captures all the aspects of what I am trying to do:

```
(* Create some offsetted data, and a zero data set. *)
myData = Table[Table[Table[RandomInteger[{1, 100}], {k, 500}], {j, 400}], {i, 200}];
myZero = Table[RandomInteger[{1, 9}]/RandomInteger[{1, 9}] + 50, {i, 500}];

(* Method 1 *)
myData = Table[
   f1 = myData[[i]];
   Table[
     f2 = f1[[j]];
     f2 - myZero, {j, 400}], {i, 200}];

(* Method 2 *)
Do[
 Do[
  myData[[i]][[j]] = myData[[i]][[j]] - myZero, {j, 400}], {i, 200}]

(* Method 3 *)
Attributes[Zeroing] = {HoldFirst};
Zeroing[x_] := Module[{}, 
   Do[
     Do[
       x[[i]][[j]] = x[[i]][[j]] - myZero, {j, Length[x[[1]]]}
       ], {i, Length[x]}
     ]
 ];
```

(Note:  Hat tip to [Aaron Honecker](http://forums.wolfram.com/student-support/topics/3065) for Method #3.)

On my machine (Intel Core2 Duo CPU 3.17 GHz, 4 GB RAM, 32-bit Windows 7), all three methods use roughly 1.25 GB of memory, with #2 and #3 fairing slightly better.

If I don't mind losing precision, wrapping `N[ ]` around the innards of `myData` and `myZero` when they're being created increases their size in memory by 150 MB initially but reduces the amount of memory required for zeroing (by methods #1-#3 above) from 1.25 GB down to just 300 MB!  That's my working solution, but it would be great to know the best way of handling this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately I have little time now, so I must be concise ...

When working with large data, you need to be aware that Mathematica has a different storage format called *packed arrays* which is much more compact and much faster than the regular one, but only works for machine reals or integers.

Please evaluate `` ?Developer`*Packed* `` to see what functions are available for directly converting to/from them, if this doesn't happen automatically.

So the brief explanation behind why my solution is fast and memory efficient is that it uses packed arrays.  I tested using `` Developer`PackedArrayQ `` that my arrays never get unpacked, and I used machine reals (I applied `N[]` to everything)

```
In[1]:= myData = N@RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {200, 400, 500}];

In[2]:= myZero = 
  Developer`ToPackedArray@
   N@Table[RandomInteger[{1, 9}]/RandomInteger[{1, 9}] + 50, {i, 500}];

In[3]:= myData = Map[# - myZero &, myData, {2}]; // Timing

Out[3]= {1.516, Null}
```

Also, the operation you were asking for ("I would like to scan through each element, and change it at that location in memory") is called mapping (see `Map[]` or `/@`).

Comment: It seems that the prefix `N@` in myData significantly reduces the memory required for mapping.  Is it true that mapping floating point numbers vs. fractions is significantly more memory efficient in the limit of long lists?

Comment: @higgy The situation is that `myZero` won't pack as rationals. So it is not so much that mapping is faster or slower per se but that `myZero` is unpacked if it you do not convert to reals. Packing only works with heads `Integer`, `Real`, `Complex`

Comment: Why I am not seeing any timing difference in `In[2]` above, when using `ToPackedArray@` vs. not using it at all? I am using V 8.04 on windows

Answer (score 3):

Let me start by noting that this answer must be viewed as complementary to the one by @Szabolcs, with the latter being, in my conclusion, the better option. While the solution of @Szabolcs is probably the fastest and best overall, it falls short of the original spec in that `Map` returns a (modified) copy of the original list, rather than  "scan each element, and change it at that location in memory". Such behavior, AFAIK,  is only provided by `Part` command. I will use his ideas (converting everything into packed arrays), to show the code that does in-memory changes to the original list:

```
In[5]:= 
Do[myData[[All,All,i]]=myData[[All,All,i]]- myZero[[i]],
     {i,Last@Dimensions@myData}];//Timing

Out[5]= {4.734,Null}
```

This is conceptually equivalent to method 3 listed in the question, but runs much faster because this is a partly vectorized solution and only a single loop is needed. This is however still at least order of magnitude slower than the solution of @Szabolcs.

*In theory*, this seems to be a classic speed/memory tradeoff: if you need speed and have some spare memory, @Szabolcs's solution is the way to go. If your memory requirements are tough, *in theory* this slower method would save on *intermediate* memory consumption (in the method of @Szabolcs, the original list is garbage-collected after the `myData` is assigned the result of `Map`, so the final memory usage is the same, but *during* the computation, one extra array of the size of `myData` is maintained by `Map`).

*In practice*, however, the memory consumption seems to not be smaller, since an extra copy of the list is for some reason maintained in the `Out` variable in both cases *during* (or right after) the computation, even when the output is suppressed (it may also be that this effect does not manifest itself in all cases). I don't quite understand this yet, but my current conclusion is that the method of @Szabolcs is just as good in terms of *intermediate* memory consumption as the present one based on the in-place list modifications. Therefore, his method seems the way to go in all cases, but I still decided to publish this answer as a complementary.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the transformation in my solution is not in-place.  I realized this after I posted the answer but I didn't have time to come back and detail it.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'd do that in comments but I couldn't squeeze all what I wanted to say into one or two comments. Besides, your solution  anyway turned out to be better for this problem than in-place one. If you feel like it, edit your answer accordingly. I am trying to be as precise as I can (and Mathematica does not make this an easy task), at the risk of being pedantic and annoying, because it is easy for new users to get confused, and to keep my own mind in a clear state (the latter is less important :))

Comment: I think you should use answers more often, we were just saying in chat that many interesting points get lost in comments!  I was aware my answer was incomplete, just didn't have time for a longer one then.